# Scrape value from table of webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to retrieve the match data from the following website:

https://understat.com/match/81

I wrote the following script:

```
import sys
import time 
import os
import io
import csv

from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as ec
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = None
cnx = None
currentDir = sys.path[0]

def scrap_understat():
   init_browser('firefox')

   for i in range(80, 10080):
      try:
         driver.get('https://understat.com/match/' + str(i))
         time.sleep(1)
         if try_find_Element(driver, By.CLASS_NAME, 'error-code') is not None:
            continue

         data = get_match_data()
         save_data(data)

      except Exception as ex:
         log_this(ex)
         print(str(ex))

   close_browser()


def get_match_data():
   data = []

   teams = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'team')

   for team in teams:
       team.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following-sibling::*').click()
       time.sleep(1)
       players = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'match-rosters').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
       for player in players:
           tds = player.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
           record = [tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text, tds[4].text,
                  tds[5].text, tds[6].text, tds[7].text, tds[8].text, tds[9].text]
           data.append(record)

   return data


def save_data(data):
# save CSV
  csv_file_path = currentDir + '/output' + current_time + '.csv'
  file = None
  writer = None
  if not os.path.exists(csv_file_path):
     file = io.open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
     writer = csv.writer(file)
     writer.writerow(
        ['player', 'pos', 'min', 'sh', 'g', 'kp', 'a', 'xG',
         'xA'])
  else:
      file = io.open(csv_file_path, 'a', newline='', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
      writer = csv.writer(file)
  for record in data:
      writer.writerow(record)
      file.close()
```

The output of my script looks like this:

[image]

So, there is a problem with the xG- and xA-columns.  I only want the lowerscript-part whereas the script takes all the text within the *td* How do I change my script to only include the first part? By inspecting the page elements, I see that the undesired part is called *sub-class*

Second question: How do I get the teamname declared as variable (Manchester United / Tottenham Hotspurs)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to avoid matching sub text:

```
record = [tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text, tds[4].text,
                  tds[5].text, tds[6].text, tds[7].text,
          driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent', tds[8]), 
          driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent', tds[9])]
```

To get teamnames you can use

```
home = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="team-home"]').text
away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="team-away"]').text
```

P.S. Consider to use [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) instead of `time.sleep`

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works perfectly. One last little question, if I want to specify the corresponding team within the *for player in players*-loop, how can I do this

Comment: @HJA24 , try `for team in teams: team_name = team.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::label').text`. You can then use `team_name` in players loop - this value will be the same for all team players

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to remove the `sup`'s:

```
driver.execute_script("$('sup').remove()")
```